# I want to add values entered into text boxes into table row by row. But here its replacing the previous values. Following is my code in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
  How should I do this?
    var InputValues=React.createClass({
      handleClick:function(){
        this.props.onUserInput(this.refs.idInputText.value,this.refs.nameInputText.value);
    },
    render:function(){
      return(
        <div>
        <form>
          <label id="id">Id: </label><br/>
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter id" ref="idInputText"   />
          <br/><br/><label id="name">Name: </label><br/>
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Name"  ref="nameInputText"   />
          <p>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
          </p>
        </form>
          </div>
      );
    }
    });

    var DisplayEmployeeTable=React.createClass({
        getInitialState:function(){
        return{
          id:'',
          nameText:''
        }
      },
      handleUserInput:function(idText,nameText)
      {
        this.setState({id:idText, nameText:nameText});
      },
      render:function(){
        return(
          <div>
            <InputValues onUserInput = {this.handleUserInput}/>
            <EmployeeTable
              idText={this.state.id}
              nameText={this.state.nameText}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
         return (
          <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>{this.props.idText}</td>   //pass array values
              <td>{this.props.nameText}</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        );
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <DisplayEmployeeTable/>,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="src/employee.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use array instead of object in `DisplayEmployeeTable` like this:

```
var InputValues=React.createClass({
  handleClick:function(){
    this.props.onUserInput(this.refs.idInputText.value,this.refs.nameInputText.value);
  },
  render:function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <label id="id">Id: </label><br/>
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter id" ref="idInputText"   />
          <br/><br/><label id="name">Name: </label><br/>
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Name"  ref="nameInputText"   />
          <p>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

 var DisplayEmployeeTable=React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
      return{
        tableInfo: []
      }
    },
    handleUserInput:function(idText,nameText)
    {
      var newTableInfo = this.state.tableInfo;      
      newTableInfo.push({id:idText, nameText:nameText});
      this.setState({
        tableInfo: newTableInfo
      });
    },
    render:function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <InputValues onUserInput = {this.handleUserInput}/>
          <EmployeeTable
            tableInfo={this.state.tableInfo}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var tableInfo = this.props.tableInfo;
     return (
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          { tableInfo.map(function(tableRow, index) {
              return (
                <tr key={'row' + index}>
                  <td>{tableRow.id}</td>   //pass array values
                  <td>{tableRow.nameText}</td>
                </tr>
              );
              })            
          }
      </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <DisplayEmployeeTable/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/25795/)